# How to join two entities with @ManyToOne annotation where fields are VARCHAR and BIGINT

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Is it possible to cast a type when joining tables with Hibernate?

I have two `@Entity` classes. The `BIGINT` type is the primary key in the first table. In the second table, the foreign key is the `VARCHAR` type.
`VARCHAR` is mandatory because the main entity joins tables where the main key is a `String`, but in one of the tables, the key is `Long`.
For `VARCHAR` types, everything works fine, but when trying to execute a query for `BIGINT`, it receives an error message:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = bigint
No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Audited
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

...

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "access_link")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "bindingType", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class BindingAccessEntity extends BaseEntity {
}
```

```
@Getter
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(RevAccessEntity.DISCRIMINATOR)
@Where(clause = "binding_type='" + RevAccessEntity.DISCRIMINATOR + "'")
public class RevAccessEntity extends BindingAccessEntity {

    static final String DISCRIMINATOR = "REV";

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "bindingId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private RevEntity rev;

}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "rev")
public class RevEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

...

    @NotAudited
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "rev")
    private List<RevAccessEntity> accessLevel;

}
```

Comment: Having a foreign key column with a different data type than the referenced primary key is a huge mistake to begin with. In fact, Postgres won't let you even create a proper foreign key in that case. The only sensible solution to your problem is to change the data type of the foreign key column to `bigint`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `bindingId` is the varchar column? In that case you can configure how the value should be read by using `@ColumnTransformer(forColumn = "bindingId", read = "cast(bindingId as bigint)")` but I would suggest you instead add a column `GENERATED ALWAYS AS cast(bindingId as bigint) STORED` to the table to avoid performance issues.